# EditText not showing text

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-edittext

Dictionary app with `listview`, `Button` and `EditText`. 
EditText show keyboard in real device on the first click but it is not showing words and
then it doesn't appear again. 
I tried many times to find a solution in stack overflow but none of them worked for me.
Any one can help?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView listView;
List<WordTranslation> quotes;
Button searchBtn;
EditText editText;
DatabaseAccess databaseAccess;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.show();
    alert.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    searchBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    editText.requestFocus();
    searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        String word=    editText.getText().toString();
            databaseAccess.getwordtranslation(word);
        }
    });


    this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    final DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    databaseAccess.getQuotes();
    quotes = databaseAccess.ShowDictionaryDetails();
    databaseAccess.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new Adapter(this, R.layout.activity_list_view_item, quotes);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.future.DictionaryEdition.MainActivity"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">



<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/line2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line1">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ListView">


    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="True"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/line1">
    <!--android:layout_alignRight="@+id/line3">-->


    <!--<SearchView-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/search_view"/>-->


    <EditText
        android:hint="@string/search_word_here"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/EditText"
        android:focusable="True"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:inputType="text" />


    <Button
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout> </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: make sure the text color does not match that of the background.

Comment: yes, it's different

Answer (score 0):

Because as you can see in the xml file you write nothing in the `android:text` field. so it give you nothing written. So change it.

```
<EditText
        android:text="balabalbla"
        android:hint="@string/search_word_here"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/EditText"
        android:focusable="True"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:inputType="text" />
```

and write something on `android:text="baablaabla"`

Comment: I uploaded the file without editing, I delete it currently,

Comment: with no difference.

Comment: try to `clean` and `rebuild` the project.